# How to expand a textField in flutter looks like a text Area

Tags: android, dart, flutter, textfield

When i tap in textField in landScape mode i would like to expand in full screen likes whatsapp

[image]

```
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.person,
                        size: 40.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  hintText: "Input your opinion",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(25.0))),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 25.0,
              ),
              controller: host,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return "Empty value";
                }
              },
            )
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: you can try setting the keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline when the textfield is in focus and the orientation is landscape

Answer (score 94, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `maxLines` variable when creating a `TextField`.
I have added the text field inside a Card widget so you can see the total area.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Material App"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                maxLines: 8, //or null 
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Enter your text here"),
              ),
            )
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 72):

Set **maxLines** to  *null* and **keyboardType** to *TextInputType.multiline* like this:

```
TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
)
```

Comment: Great solution! How can we achieve sentenceCapitalization while still using multiline?

Comment: For future seekers: set `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences` in the TextField

Answer (score 42):

To achieve the exact look of the text area you can use this

```
TextFormField(
   minLines: 6, // any number you need (It works as the rows for the textarea)
   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
   maxLines: null,
)
```

Here is the output (Some extra styling will needed)
[image]

Enjoy....

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, there is no way in flutter you can set the minimum height of a TextField or TextFormField. 
The best way to give a TextField or a TextFormField a fixed size is to specify the maximum lines the Field should take without expanding farther. Note: This does not limit the amount of input text, it only limits the number of lines shown.

Example:

```
                             TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                maxLines: 8,
                                maxLength: 1000,

                              ),
```

This will limit the size of the field to 8 lines, but can take as much as 1000 characters.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: That's not totally right I think. hintText with '\n' will expand the TextField's height. See my answer below.

Comment: @JChen___ What do you mean is not right, you mean adding a lot of line feeds (\n) to a hint text is the best solution. Don't you know that as soon as you start typing the hint text disappears?

Comment: Yes it disappears, but the expanded height keeps.

Answer (score 16):

##### Screenshot:

[image]

Set **`minLines`** to a non-null value  and **`maxLines`** to null (explicitly). Set `TextCapitalization.sentences` if you want to make the next character uppercase after a period.

```dart
TextField(
  minLines: 3,
  maxLines: null,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
TextFormField(
          minLines: 6,
          maxLines: null,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Enter text',
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set maxLines to null and set keyboardType to TextInputType.multiline will make TextField's height to grow up with your input.

And hintText with '\n' may expand the TextField's height at the start.

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: '内容',
      hintText: '描述下发生的事情吧！\n\n\n\n\n'),

),
```

Here is the output.

With focus.
[image: With focus.]

Without focus.
[image: Without focus]

Answer (score 1):

If your textField widget is Column's child widget and set `expands: true` .

Can set `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top` to align text in the top.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution for the text area
If you have multiple textarea in your UI then you have to specify maxlines in them.
Use this code to create a common component and it will expend according to content

```
TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
)
```